# Hikari CP: Connection acquire time

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, grafana, hikaricp

I am monitoring Spring Boot application in production using Prometheus and Grafana. And sometimes I see that the max connection acquire time for Hikari CP () takes too long (10-20 seconds).

[image: hikaricp_connections_acquire_seconds_max]

As I can see, it is not correlated with Oracle activity and number of active connections in Hikari. But it makes Spring Data queries slow. Sometimes I have to restart the app to bring the CP performance back.

This is my HikariCP configuration:

```
  datasource:
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=dbhost)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(SID=ORADB)(SERVER=SHARED)))         
jdbcUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=dbhost)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(SID=ORADB)(SERVER=SHARED)))
username: tm
password: P@ssw0rd
hikari:
  poolName: Hikari
  maximum-pool-size: 300
  auto-commit: false
  max-lifetime: 900000
  leak-detection-threshold: 30000
  idle-timeout: 900000
  connectionTimeout: 30000
  data-source-properties:
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 250
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    useServerPrepStmts: true
```

Could somebody advise where could be the problem?

Comment: When you're saying `"As I can see, it is not correlated with Oracle activity and number of active connections in Hikari"` do you mean the application is not under heavy load and you're not actually running out of free connections?

Comment: @Strelok, exactly. Number of HikariCP active connection does never exceeds 50.